# Copy and resize a document and fit it into box

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I'm using PDFsharp to create a PDF.

I am trying to copy another document/image (PDF format with A3 size) and paste it within the image box, in the new document (A4 size).

In the new document, there would be an image details box and an image box.

So, how do I copy the image from another PDF into the image box in the new document?

Below is the sample I need to create using PDFsharp.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw pages from other PDF files like you draw images - draw them anywhere at any angle and any size.
You may have to do some calculations to maintain the aspect ratio.

See the Two Pages on One sample:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx
Lines 40 and 54 draw PDF pages. Check the lines above for prerequisites.